# How to fill a text field in a collectionview cell after returning from popover

Tags: ios7, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

Can anyone please help me... I have a collection view that displays data retrieved from a SQLite database. Certain text fields in the collection view cells need to be updated using a pre-defined list in a pop-over.

The popover displays the right values, and I do retrieve the selected value but I cannot manage to update the text field in the collectionview with the value. I assume that I need to specify the cell that contains the text field using the indexpath upon starting the segue, but I do not know how.

I start the popover using this:

```
-(BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField{
    if (textField.tag == 101) {
        Global.Table = @"Access";
        Global.Code = @"G";
        Global.Request = @"Access";
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"PopUp" sender:self];
        return NO;
    }
    else {
        return YES;
    }
}
```

The popover sends a notification after selecting the correct value in a tableview and gets dismissed.

```
- (void)receivedNotification:(NSNotification *) notification {
    if ([[notification name] isEqualToString:@"scroller"]) {
        if ([Global.Request isEqualToString:@"Access"]) {
          NSLog(@"Returnvalue is %@",Global.Value);

          //this is where the problem arises, I cannot access the text field to update the value, the return value is correct.

          [self.collectionviewManagement selectItemAtIndexPath:0 animated:NO scrollPosition:0];

          WDSCellManagement *cell = [_collectionviewManagement dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"CellManagement" forIndexPath:0];
          cell.AccessPersons.text = Global.Value;
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You use a delegation pattern, as with any view controller interaction:

YourPopupController.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@class YourPopViewController;

@protocol YourPopupViewControllerDelegate <NSObject>
@optional
- (void)yourPopupViewController:(YourPopViewController *)yourPopupViewController
                  returnedValue:(NSString *)value;
@end

@interface YourPopupViewController : UITableViewController
@property (weak, nonatomic) id<YourPopupViewControllerDelegate> delegate;
@end
```

YourPopupViewController.m:

```
- (void)receivedNotification:(NSNotification *) notification {
    if ([[notification name] isEqualToString:@"scroller"]) {
        if ([Global.Request isEqualToString:@"Access"]) {
          if ([_delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(yourPopupViewController:returnedValue:)]) {
              [_delegate yourPopupViewController:self
                                   returnedValue:Global.Value];
          }
        }
    }
}
```

You then conform to the `YourPopupViewControllerDelegate` protocol in your *presenting* view controller and update the collection view when the delegate method is called, dismissing the popup view controller.